# Vue components not showing up in laravel project

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I am working in Laravel , and Vue components are showing/updating in local but not showing in server .
I don't know what the problem is,because I have all the packages of vue and node installed on the server.[image]

app.js picture is:
[image]

i used npm run dev ,npm run production npm run watch They all worked without error but still show nothing

please help me What can I do؟

Answer (score 1):

You didn't call your component in `dashboard.blade.php` file.

```
<div id="app">
   <login-component></login-component>
</div>
```

Or if you want to call example component then:

```
<div id="app">
   <login-component></login-component>
</div>
```

Comment: no no , i have a  App component  that connected to div with id=app

Comment: Your vue instance is attached to selector #app, which means inside of element with id `app` you can call your vue components. For using your components you should call them.